# LDAP authentification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ldap

I am in charge of creating a new laravel project where the authentication is made by our LDAP. I am pretty new to laravel so excuse me for my lack of comprehension

I am trying to use this library : [Adldap2-Laravel](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel)

I followed [this documentation](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md) to build the authentification from scratch.

So my **config/app.php** have those lines added

```
//In providers array
Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class,
Adldap\Laravel\AdldapAuthServiceProvider::class,

//In aliases
'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class,
```

And my **config/auth.php** (I also tried to only use the adldap driver, without success)

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'adldap',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Everything looks right. But I can not auth, I have this error : `These credentials do not match our records.`

When I use this code

```
use Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap;

$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPassword";

if (Adldap::auth()->attempt($username, $password)) {
    //Queries here
}
else
{
    echo "Auth failed";
}
```

I CAN perform queries, and the authentication works with all my users. But I can not use properly the login form behind the "Login" button.

Did I miss something ?

---

I do not know if the authentication should work directly without importing anything but I also tried to run this command

```
php artisan adldap:import
```

All my users are found and inserted in the laravel DB. But the authentication still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the `ADLDAP_ACCOUNT_SUFFIX=` from my **.env** file

And added the suffix directly in `ADLDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME=Administrator@mycompany.something`

Now I'm able to connect via the email address.

I do not know if it is the best solution but at least it works.

---

I let this post open for a few days to see if someone have a better idea